# How to know if a process is attached to a tap interface?

Tags: networking, process, kvm, tap

I sometimes come upon machine with tap interfaces (eg, when KVM is running). How can I know which process is attached to the TAP interface?

Comment: I suspect you can do this with `nmap`, but I'm not sure how to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This got me wondering and I had a look at the Linux kernel source (I'm assuming your question is about Linux).

It appears the answer's more difficult than you'd expect. This [TUN/TAP API tutorial page offers some insight](http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/). Basically, your program allocates a new TUN/TAP device by opening `/dev/net/tun` and sending it the `TUNSETIFF` `ioctl`. If all goes well, an interface is created, the kernel gives you its name and a file descriptor, and that's how you manage it.

There are two catches here:

1. The kernel doesn't store the PID of the process that sent the ioctl in `struct tun_struct` (TUN and TAP largely share the same data structures).
2. A process may mark an interface as persistent, close its file descriptor and thereafter use it as a normal network interface.

In practice, I suspect 2 doesn't happen much. Checking out an `openvpn` process with `lsof` reveals it's still got its file descriptor to the TAP device open and obviously using it, but since `/dev/net/tun` is a sort of multiplexing device like `/dev/ptmx`, you can use `lsof` to find out what processes are currently using a TUN/TAP device, but you can't know what process is using what device.

There are oblique ways of solving the underlying problem. For OpenVPN, I use a tunnel setup script that names the `tunX`/`tapX` devices with a more descriptive name that includes the basename of the OpenVPN config file. So, `/etc/openvpn/foo.conf` leads to a `vpn-foo` device. Then I can correlate the OpenvVPN process with the interface it's using. Haven't had to do this with QEmu/KVM yet, though.

Comment: Ok. I was suspecting too that the "multiplexing" /dev/net/tun would prevent us to know what tap interface exactly a process is attached too.

Answer (score 5):

Each file descriptor has  a /proc/*pid*/fdinfo/*num* entry, like:

```
# cat /proc/24332/fdinfo/28
pos:    0
flags:  0104002
mnt_id: 18
iff:    tap0123acdc-66
```

So, with the interface name, you can get the pid with:

```
# egrep -l iff:.*tap0123acdc-66 /proc/*/fdinfo/* 2>/dev/null|cut -d/ -f3
24332
```

Comment: Works for me:
`% sudo bash -c 'grep -l iff:.*vnet0 /proc/*/fdinfo/* 2>/dev/null | cut -d/ -f3' `
`4143`
`% pgrep qemu`
`4143`

Given the fact that there is a name parameter shown in the output of `ps -ef` for qemu processes, e.g. `qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -name debian-8` it should be easy to find out to which VM a pid and an interface corresponds to.

Answer (score 1):

On FreeBSD or any other BSD derivative:

```
ifconfig tap0
```

should show you which process is connected to the interface:

```
tap0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=80000<LINKSTATE>
    ether 58:9c:fc:10:8f:2b
    groups: tap
    media: Ethernet autoselect
    status: active
    nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    Opened by PID 2672
```

Comment: What OS and version are you trying this on? It'd be VERY handy to have this information (I run a box with dozens of VPN endpoints), but the Debian `ifconfig` doesn't show this. Mind you, these are `tap` devices created by OpenVPN — though I don't see why there should be a difference.

Comment: This is about FreeBSD or any other BSD derivative.