# How to find the connection between tap interface and its file descriptor?

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu, tap

I have a `qemu` VM started by an orchestration script, which creates transient `tap` interfaces. When I inspect the command line arguments of the `qemu-system-x86_64` process, then I can see, that the process connects to already opened `tap` interface with the file descriptor `27`:

```
-netdev tap,fd=27,id=hostnet1,vhost=on,vhostfd=28
```

According to `ls -l /proc/<qemu-system-x86_64_PID>/fd/27` it points to `/dev/net/tun`.

Does it work somehow in a way that `tap` interface name (for example `vnet99`) is passed to `/dev/net/tun` with `ioctl()` and this returns the correct fd? Or in general, how can I find out which `tap` interface in my host machine has file descriptor 27?

Comment: answer (well reverse problem, but info is the same): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217977/251756

Comment: Explains how `/dev/net/tun` works - https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt?id=HEAD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`iff:`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/drivers/net/tun.c#L3294) entry which [could have given](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217977/251756) [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462208/251756) was [added in kernel 3.14](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.14/ident/tun_chr_show_fdinfo) with the commit [`tun: add device name(iff) field to proc fdinfo entry`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?h=v3.14&id=93e14b6d776e850a371fe4234a06088f210d8651), so is not available on kernel 3.13 or before, eg with Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

In this case, while it's not possible to ask the kernel to give the information, it's still possible to ask the *actual process* to give this information, by tracing it with a debugger.

There's an ioctl available since Linux 2.6.27 to ask informations about a configured [tuntap interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt): [`TUNGETIFF`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/ident/TUNGETIFF). Its use is for a process inheriting an *fd* to be able to query the *fd* to receive interface's name and type ([`ifr_name` and `ifr_flags`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/drivers/net/tun.c#L2714)) or to know the tuntap device was not configured yet (`EBADFD`) and that it should do it.

So while it's possible using [`gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), it's a bit tricky because if no development environment is available, a few needed parameter and values have to be known or adjusted (and might change in the future or with architectures). These informations and adjustments where needed here:

- defining [`$malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947435/mallocd-memory-cannot-be-accessed-gdb?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment82864905_47947435) for 64bits systems to handle the correct size for the returned memory address: credit goes to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947435/mallocd-memory-cannot-be-accessed-gdb?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment82864905_47947435) from SO.
- `$malloc(64)`: [`struct ifreq`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/include/uapi/linux/if.h#L231) appears to be 40 bytes on 64bits, let's use 64 to stay safe.
- `0x800454d2` == `TUNGETIFF`.
- result `ifr_name` is at offset 0.

Here are a shell script preparing the way for each tuntap fd found to call `gdb`, along with gdb's own script:

`tungetiff.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ $# -gt 0 ] || exit 1
SCRIPTGDB="$1"; shift

for pid in "$@"; do
    for procfd in /proc/$pid/fd/*; do
        if [ "$(readlink $procfd)" = "/dev/net/tun" ]; then
            fd=$(basename $procfd)
            printf 'pid=%d fd=%d ifname=' $pid $fd
            gdb -batch-silent --pid=$pid -ex 'set $fd'=$fd -x "$SCRIPTGDB"
        fi
    done
done
```

`tungetiff.gdb`:

```
set $malloc=(void *(*)(long long)) malloc
p $malloc(64)
p ioctl($fd, 0x800454d2, $1)
set *((char *)($1+16))=0
set logging file /dev/stdout
set logging on
printf "%s\n",$1
set logging off
call free($1)
quit
```

Typical example of execution (will probably only work as root, even user libvirt-qemu doesn't appear to be able to [ptrace](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages-dev/ptrace.2.en.html) qemu-system):

```
# ./tungetiff.sh tungetiff.gdb $(pgrep qemu-system-)
pid=22281 fd=26 ifname=vnet1
pid=22281 fd=30 ifname=vnet2
pid=27109 fd=26 ifname=vnet0
```

Answer (score 3):

With the file descriptor 27 known you'd walk the `/proc` under the QEMU's process:

```
 $ ls /proc/<qemu-system-x86_64_PID>/fd/27
```

At the same level as the `fd` directory is another directory `fdinfo` which contains details such as this:

```
$ cat /proc/<qemu-system-x86_64_PID>/fdinfo/27
pos:    0
flags:  0104002
mnt_id: 18
iff:    tap0123acdc-66
```

The `iff` entry in this file is the tap device.

#### References

- [How to know if a process is attached to a tap interface?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40557/how-to-know-if-a-process-is-attached-to-a-tap-interface)
- [root/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt Kernel docs](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt?id=HEAD)

Comment: At least in Linux `3.13.0-32-generic` the `fd` file in `fdinfo` does not contain the `mnt_id` and `iff` fields.

Comment: @Martin - interesting, what's the distro?