# Get which /dev/tapX got associated to a macvtap without guessing

Tags: linux, networking, devices, qemu, iproute

Following [this](https://virt.kernelnewbies.org/MacVTap) guide to setup a `macvtap` works great.
An excerpt from the guide loosk like this:

```bsh
# ip link add link eth1 name macvtap0 type macvtap
# ip link set macvtap0 address 1a:46:0b:ca:bc:7b up
# ip link show macvtap0
```

The guide then goes on to explain that you can do:

```bsh
#qemu-system-x86_64 -net nic,model=virtio,addr=1a:46:0b:ca:bc:7b -net tap,fd=3 3<>/dev/tap11
```

And that works great, if your `macvtap` ends up on `/dev/tap11`.
But how do you check which `/dev/tapX` interface actually got assigned to the `macvtap0` above?

I have quite a lot of services setting up tap devices on my machine at random times. And I can't guess which one my specific one ended up on.

I was hoping that booting the qemu machine with:

```bsh
    -netdev tap,ifname="macvtap0",id=network0,script=no,downscript=no \
    -device i82559b,netdev=network0,mac=${MAC}
```

Would work, where `macvtap0` is the device I've just created.
However, that gives me:

`qemu-system-x86_64: could not configure /dev/net/tun (macvtap0): Invalid argument`

Outlined in this article: [How to find the connection between tap interface and its file descriptor?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462171/how-to-find-the-connection-between-tap-interface-and-its-file-descriptor) - they describe a way to do it by accessing the PID and check associated file descriptors, problem here for me is that qemu isn't setting up the device, I am. And there's no PID associated with it.

Sow how can I get the file-handle under `/dev` associated with the newly created `macvtap` interface?

**Edit:** I'm already a few days in on this problem, but I just realised that I forgot to check `/sys/class/net/macvtap0/`, and there is a `/tap2` device. Obivously I need to iterate through all the contents still to find a name matching `regex(tap[0-9]+)`. This will work, but not sure it's the best/correct way to do this.

Comment: So, did you ever check my answer to your question?

Comment: @A.B I'm getting around to it. Been a very hectic year. But I'm still highly interested in this, just haven't been around setting up virtual interfaces for a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The device name is [created](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/macvtap.c?h=v5.4#n170) based upon the [interface index](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/macvtap.c?h=v5.4#n157):

> ```
> snprintf(tap_name, IFNAMSIZ, "tap%d", dev->ifindex);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>       devt = MKDEV(MAJOR(macvtap_major), vlantap->tap.minor);
>       classdev = device_create(&macvtap_class, &dev->dev, devt,
>                    dev, tap_name);
> ```

If OP's `ip link show macvtap0`'s answer was present it would most likely begin with:

```
11: macvtap0@eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 [...]
```

- This property is [being](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2011-09/msg03778.html) [used](https://gist.github.com/mcastelino/43cc733e53d65ef67452ecaf78e936c2#how-to-launch-qemu-from-command-line-without-libvirt-with-macvtap-and-vhost-support) or [documented](https://backreference.org/2014/03/20/some-notes-on-macvlanmacvtap/) [in a few places](https://seravo.fi/2012/virtualized-bridged-networking-with-macvtap).

  ```
  $ echo /dev/tap$(cat /sys/class/net/macvtap0/ifindex)
  /dev/tap11
  ```

---

If you don't want to rely on this specific property which doesn't appear to be officially documented (the word *macvtap* doesn't exist in the whole `linux/Documentation/` tree), you can rely on the entries in `/sys` (which don't appear either to be officially documented for *macvtap*):

The informations are available in the `macvtap/*` subdir. Note that `tap11` is a symlink to the single entry `macvtap/tap11` and since it's impractical where it is, it should be ignored (but not the directory it points to).

- From network *interface name* find device node entry name:

  1. `/sys/class/net/macvtap0/macvtap/*` has a single entry, the tap device name, which is a directory:

     ```
     $ printf '/dev/%s\n' "$(basename /sys/class/net/macvtap0/macvtap/*)"
     /dev/tap11
     ```

     A function called `intf_to_devtap` could be used:

     ```
     intf_to_devtap () {
         [ -e "/sys/class/net/$1/macvtap" ] || return 1
         printf '/dev/%s\n' "$(basename /sys/class/net/$1/macvtap/*)"
     }
     ```

     For OP's case:

     ```
     $ intf_to_devtap macvtap0
     /dev/tap11
     ```
  2. `dev` entry for *major:minor*:

     ```
     $ cat /sys/class/net/macvtap0/macvtap/*/dev
     242:1
     ```

     This property (and the equivalent below in `uevent`) is the only guaranteed to be unique in case there are *macvtap* created in multiple network namespaces, each with the same interface index, thus making a device node *name* collision. Example of collision (when no *macvtap* device were created before):

     ```
     # ip netns add collision1; ip netns add collision2
     # ip -n collision1 link add type dummy; ip -n collision2 link add type dummy
     # ip -n collision1 link add link dummy0 type macvtap
     # ls -l /dev/tap*
     crw-------. 1 root root 242, 1 Apr 19 21:24 /dev/tap3
     # ip -n collision2 link add link dummy0 type macvtap
     # ls -l /dev/tap*
     crw-------. 1 root root 242, 1 Apr 19 21:24 /dev/tap3
     ```

     A second tap entry didn't appear. That's because there was a collision when the second network namespace also created an interface with index 3 (`lo`=1, `dummy0`=2, `macvtap0`=3), and the second device entry wasn't created in `/dev` because a file of the same name already existed. As `ip netns` also remounts `/sys` for accurate handling of network devices, one can verify that actually two tap devices exist, even if the second one wasn't "mapped":

     ```
     # ip netns exec collision1 sh -c 'cat /sys/class/net/macvtap0/macvtap/*/dev'
     242:1
     # ip netns exec collision2 sh -c 'cat /sys/class/net/macvtap0/macvtap/*/dev'
     242:2
     ```

     So one could still use the 2nd *macvtap* interface backend by "mapping" and then using the device, even if half of `/sys` informations won't match this, for example:

     ```
     # mknod /dev/tap3b c 242 2
     ```

     or with a more verbose name like `/dev/tap-VM1-intfA`.
  3. `uevent` entry, giving both major:minor and name:

     ```
     $ cat /sys/class/net/macvtap0/macvtap/*/uevent
     MAJOR=242
     MINOR=1
     DEVNAME=tap11
     ```
- From *dev* entry to interface name:

  With `/dev/tap11`:

  `/dev/tap11` -> `/sys/class/macvtap/tap11` -> `/sys/devices/virtual/net/macvtap0/macvtap/tap11`. Note that `/sys/class/net/macvtap0` before is actually a symlink to `/sys/devices/virtual/net/macvtap0`.

  Still in the last directory, the `device` entry is a symlink to the interface directory, so we have in the end `/sys/class/macvtap/tap11/device` -> `/sys/devices/virtual/net/macvtap0`

  A function called `devtap_to_intf` could be used:

  ```
  devtap_to_intf () {
      [ -c "$1" ] || [ -c "/dev/$1" ] || return 1
      local path="$(readlink -e "/sys/class/macvtap/${1#/dev/}/device")"
      printf '%s\n' "${path#/sys/devices/virtual/net/}"
  }
  ```

  With OP's case:

  ```
  $ devtap_to_intf /dev/tap11
  macvtap0
  ```

Comment: Apologies it took so long time. Great work, and really appreciated all the descriptions of the steps. I'm still a bit puzzled, but at least I get the concept and where to look : )